# Connect to CUPS web interface of Ubuntu instance on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, cups

I have installed *CUPS* on a *Ubuntu Xenial VM* instance of Google compute engine. I have changed settings as described [here](http://thismightbehelpful.blogspot.be/2008/09/remote-access-to-cups-web-interface.html) and [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/02/cups-admin-ui-access/) and restarted the CUPS server.

I'm trying to access the web interface through `http(s)://my-external-ip:631/admin` but that is not reachable. Pinging to the External IP works.

How can I troubleshoot or what extra configuration might be needed in the CUPS configuration or VM instance configuration?